# Forcing browsers to display bold text when embedded font has normal font-weight

Tags: fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts

I'm using @font-face to embed the regular variant (i.e. font-weight: normal) of [angie sans](http://typekit.com/fonts/angie-std-sans?utm_medium=colophon&utm_source=typekit-app&utm_content=font-byline-name) from typekit.

I like my h1 tags to be bold but don't want to embed an extra variant of the font just for the sake of a few words at the top of each page

So I'm using the regular variant and setting `font-weight: bold` anyway, whenever I need to.

It works fine (even for italics) but I'm aware that the user's browser is being asked to make a best-guess here and have noticed that Chrome will make individual chars appear slightly fatter than FF when I do things this way. These differences disappear when I embed the bold variant of the font.

So should I stop doing this? Is it advisable to embed the proper bold variant? Should I just change my text colour or shadow instead? Are there any browsers on which this technique backfires where text becomes unreadable?

Answer (score 1):

Embed the bold variant, give it the same `font-family` name, and a `font-weight` of `bold`